# Why does `table1` does not produce the labels as expected?

Tags: r

I am using [package table1](https://cran.r-project.org/package=table1) to produce summary tables, however the function `label()` does not work as expected:

```r
ds <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                              age = c(23.3612886594671,
                                                      23.3753110185819,
                                                      21.351562856491,21.3774626714326,
                                                      21.3614444064187,
                                                      19.4385276446878,26.4262334271301,
                                                      26.4262259487414,
                                                      19.3516767117905,23.3518315397876),
                                            ARACE = c("Chinese","Indian",
                                                      "Chinese","Chinese",
                                                      "Chinese","Chinese",
                                                      "Chinese","Chinese","Chinese",
                                                      "Chinese"),
                                             ASEX = c("Male","Female",
                                                      "Female","Female","Female",
                                                      "Female","Female",
                                                      "Female",NA,"Male")
                               )

library(table1)
label(ds$age)       <- "Age"
label(ds$ARACE)       <- "Ethnicity"

units(ds$age)       <- "years"

caption  <- "Basic stats"
footnote <- "ᵃ The labels do not work as expected."

table1(~ age + ARACE | ASEX,
               data=ds[complete.cases(ds$ASEX),],
               overall=c(left="Total"),
               caption=caption, footnote=footnote)
```

[image]

Both the word "age" and "ARACE" should have been replaced with "Age" and "Ethnicity", respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Complete Cases` dataframe first.

```
ds <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  age = c(23.3612886594671,
          23.3753110185819,
          21.351562856491,21.3774626714326,
          21.3614444064187,
          19.4385276446878,26.4262334271301,
          26.4262259487414,
          19.3516767117905,23.3518315397876),
  ARACE = c("Chinese","Indian",
            "Chinese","Chinese",
            "Chinese","Chinese",
            "Chinese","Chinese","Chinese",
            "Chinese"),
  ASEX = c("Male","Female",
           "Female","Female","Female",
           "Female","Female",
           "Female",NA,"Male"))
ds1 <- ds[complete.cases(ds$ASEX),]


label(ds1$age) <- "Age"
label(ds1$ARACE) <- "Ethnicity"

units(ds1$age) <- "years"

caption  <- "Basic stats"
footnote <- "ᵃ The labels do not work as expected."

table1(~ age + ARACE | ASEX,
       data=ds1,
       overall=c(left="Total"),
       caption=caption, footnote=footnote)
```

Output :
[image]